# how to get composite c1 adminsrtrative console logged in user details

Tags: asp.net, c1-cms

hi all composite developers, I am new one in this platform my requirement is to get the logged in user details like name and id etc..
please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use methods of the Composite.C1Console.Security.UserValidationFacade class, like:

```
 UserValidationFacade.IsLoggedIn()
 UserValidationFacade.GetUsername()
```